# Filter all data in Tabulator

Tags: javascript, tabulator

How to filter/search data by all fileds in table?

I have table like this https://prnt.sc/ot84k2

I'm looking at Tabulators filter documentation and i'm not sure how to 
filter all data by one input filter.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What have you tried? We don't have any context into your problem aside from the text you've written. This is unclear, its better to post code snippets on relevant areas so we can see where your bug is. Please refer to [ask] and or [repro] for more details about formatting and writing a good question

Answer (score 0):

**Looks like the answer is in the Documentation. [LINK](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.0?#filter)**

Use the code below, then use the "*LIKE*" comparator and type the desired name/age...etc

**HTML**

`<div id="example-table"></div>`

**JavaScript**

````
//Custom filter example

function customFilter(data){
    return data.car && data.rating < 3;
}

//Trigger setFilter function with correct parameters
function updateFilter(){

    var filter = $("#filter-field").val() == "function" ? customFilter : $("#filter-field").val();

    if($("#filter-field").val() == "function" ){
        $("#filter-type").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#filter-value").prop("disabled", true);
    }else{
        $("#filter-type").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#filter-value").prop("disabled", false);
    }

    table.setFilter(filter, $("#filter-type").val(), $("#filter-value").val());
}

//Update filters on value change
$("#filter-field, #filter-type").change(updateFilter);
$("#filter-value").keyup(updateFilter);

//Clear filters on "Clear Filters" button click
$("#filter-clear").click(function(){
    $("#filter-field").val("");
    $("#filter-type").val("=");
    $("#filter-value").val("");

    table.clearFilter());
});

//Build Tabulator
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:"311px",
    layout:"fitColumns",
    columns:[
        {title:"Name", field:"name", width:200},
        {title:"Progress", field:"progress", formatter:"progress", sorter:"number"},
        {title:"Gender", field:"gender"},
        {title:"Rating", field:"rating", formatter:"star", align:"center", width:100},
        {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
        {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", align:"center", sorter:"date"},
        {title:"Driver", field:"car", align:"center", formatter:"tickCross"},
    ],
});```
````